# remove touch event handler on element using jQuery off()

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I'm playing with a JavaScript library based on jQuery that allows for touch gestures for mobile touch devices, [toe.js](https://github.com/dantipa/toe.js).

toe.js allows me to add a `tap` event, which is similar to a click event, so I enable `tap` for all current & future `.button` elements:

```
$(document)
  .on('tap', '.button', function() {
    tapAction($(this));
  });

function tapAction($btn) {
  // do stuff
  // disable all event handlers
  $btn.off();
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to remove this event handler; `off()` isn't working... all the touch event handlers still exist on the element when I inspect it with Chrome's dev tools.

[image: event listeners]

I can do `$(document).off()`, which works, but that also removes the events for all elements, both current & future, which is not what I want :(

I've looked through toe.js's source code, and I can't find a way to unbind the events. So how do I remove all of the element's event listeners, preferably using jQuery?

Comment: Have you tried $(document).off('tap',this);

Comment: @roasted... yes I have... it doesn't seem to be working. remember, `tap` is a custom toe.js event, so it becomes the `touch*` events when added to the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with how I define the `.on()` event handlers. When using `.on()` for dynamic elements, where you pass a selector as an argument to `.on()`, you can't `.off()` a subset of the items. The reason for this is that there's only one event handler installed on the root element, in this case `document`. As such, jQuery can only remove the entire event handler, for every element being selected.

The way to overcome this is by removing the entire handler and attaching a new one with the subset of dynamic elements excluded. So...

```
// remove the entire 'tap' handler for all '.button' elements
$(document).off('tap', '.button');

// re-add the 'tap' handler for all '.button-subset' elements
// same elements as before but excluding a certain set
$(document).on('tap', '.button-subset', function() {
  tapAction($(this));
});
```

I don't quite like this solution because it seems inefficient, inelegant. What I did instead was add a `disabled` class to the buttons and check for it in the event handler...

```
$(document)
  .on('tap', '.button', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) { return false; }
    tapAction($(this));
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you can always .off each of the touch event one by one

```
$(document).on('tap', '.button', function() {
    $(this).off('touchstart', this);
    $(this).off('touchend', this);
    .....
});
```

Comment: I guess... but that is pretty ugly :/

Comment: btw... I could do this on the element itself, right? no need to do `$(document)`, right?

Comment: Well you can always file an issue so toe.js updates their code for unbinding

Comment: yea, I'll file an issue on toe.js to provide this ability. thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Hristo yes you should be able to do it on the element itself. It is better not to bind to document anyway

Comment: @Hristo, using `on()` on the document is for instances where the element itself is not part of the DOM yet. You may want to leave it as is.

Comment: I need `on()` on document because I dynamically add elements to the DOM that need this `tap` event handler

Comment: if you have a an overall container, you can target that container instead of document. You can always write a simple function to unbind the touch events yourself and use it that way, maybe extend toe.js yourself

Comment: the buttons are nested pretty deep within the DOM tree... there's a `<div id="section>` element, a `<li class="item">` element, a `<div class="buttons">` element, and then the actual button. Adding `on()` to any of these **does not work** for future buttons that get added to the DOM... it only works when I add it to document.

Answer (score 0):

Use `unbind()`

> Description: Remove a previously-attached event handler from the elements.

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: unbind() is equivalent to off(), and don't think it will change anything

Comment: `unbind()` is deprecated... supposed to use `off()` as of jQuery 1.7

Comment: @Hristo - `unbind()` is not deprecated - "Event handlers attached with .bind() can be removed with .unbind(). (As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` and `.off()` methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements.) In the simplest case, with no arguments, .unbind() removes all handlers attached to the elements"